# Tilde character is default to superscript version. How to restore default behaviour?

Tags: keyboard, mojave

I've inherited a previously used and configured MacBook Pro with Mojave (10.14.1) installed on it. I'm trying to navigate the system using the terminal but the tilde character ('~') doesn't work! Instead, what I believe to be a superscript ('˜') version of the tilde appears when I hit shift + '`'. What could be causing this, and how can I get back the default, expected behaviour ?

Answer (score 1):

After going through all the keyboard settings, it turns out that there is a difference between 'US' and 'US International PC'. The bizarre tilde behaviour was part of the 'US International PC' keyboard configuration.

Comment: Yes, US International PC is a special layout, taken from Windows, where tilde and certain other keys (` ^ ' ") serve as dead keys to create the most common accented characters in European languages.  But you can always get the non-accent version by typing space after the deadkey.