# Can you type a tilde on the key under Esc on a European ISO keyboard set to US?

Tags: macos, keyboard

I am forced to use MacBook Pro 2018. I am located in a German-speaking country, so the autodetected (or pre-installed?) keyboard layout was German.

I work as an English-speaking programmer, so I need e.g. the tilde `~`. I have added the US keyboard layout. But for some reason, on a Mac, that is next to <kbd>Shift</kbd>. The button on the laptop's keyboard, where <kbd>~</kbd> normally is, on Mac it writes `§`.

How can I set a US keyboard on a Mac with this layout that can be found in Linux?

[image]
<sup>[Source](http://kbd-intl.narod.ru/english/layouts)</sup>

Comment: It depends whether you have a physical ANSI or ISO keyboard. Could you post a picture of it? [Basically on ANSI it's below Esc, on ISO it's between shift & Z (or Y on qwertz)]

Comment: Hmm... sorry, it seems much harder to do on qwertz ISO & I can't test ansi.

Comment: Please focus on one problem at a time. Once the tilde issue is resolved, you can either use the answer you got to solve other keys yourself, or ask a second question for this.

Comment: Also, if the answer below recommending Karabiner/Ukulele doesn't help please be more specific about what you have tried and where you are stuck. It might then also be helpful to see a picture of your physical keypboard layout *and* an indication on the place you expect the tilde to be (layouts are flexible, also under Linux, so just saying "as in Linux" isn't specific enough).

Comment: @nohillside I worked with about 10 distributions and all had the same main US keyboard layout. But if it helps: [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_and_American_keyboards#/media/File:KB_United_States-NoAltGr.svg) [2](http://kbd-intl.narod.ru/english/layouts)

Comment: It helps if you post a question on a site for users of Apple products who usually are not aware of Linux keybindings.

Comment: Where the tilde is with an Apple English input source selected depends on whether your physical keyboard is ISO (extra key) or ANSI (no extra key).  If you use an external ANSI keyboard, it will be under escape. Otherwise you need a custom input source to have it there.  That is what you want, right?

Comment: For details about ANSI vs ISO layouts see https://support.getfreewrite.com/article/44-freewrites-physical-keyboard-layouts-ansi-vs-iso (just the first useful link I found)

Answer (score 7):

Having tilde next to the left shift is normal for Apple ISO (European) English keyboards.  If you want to put it somewhere else, you will have to use an app like Karabiner or Ukelele to customize the layout.

If using an external keyboard is acceptable, you could try to get an ANSI (US) keyboard (with no key between z and shift) someplace.  It will have the tilde below ESC.

Do not use the layout called "US International PC", since it treats tilde as a dead key for making accented characters, and requires [extra steps](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/341518/tilde-character-is-default-to-superscript-version-how-to-restore-default-behavi/341519#341519) to create an ASCII tilde.

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/26af8bwn0y1j7p4/US%20ISO%20HiTilde.keylayout.zip?dl=0) is a custom US layout that should put tilde under escape.

Comment: Ok let's assume I can get used to having `~` key elsewhere. But even that key writes some different character - it seems like a superscript tilde. How can I write the ASCII `~` character?

Comment: @OndraŽižka  What input source are you using where that happens?  US and the custom one I made produce ASCII tilde. If you using the one called US International PC, then switch to US, or type a space after the "superscript" tilde.

Comment: TBH, I don't know what input source do I use. It's all what came with the Mac, and it's a new one from a box. The only thing I changed so far was setting the layout in the settings to US PC.

Comment: @OndraŽižka  Get rid of "US PC".  Make sure the ONLY item in System Preferences/Keyboard/Input Sources has the name "US" or "ABC".

Comment: Adding the given custom US layout solved the issue. Appreciate your work @TomGewecke

Comment: @TomGewecke I'm curious if you know if macOS contains `.keylayout` files for the ABC (or other built-in) input sources, such that the corresponding XML file can just be modified and dropped into ~/Library/Keyboard\ Layouts, instead of going the Ukulele/karabiner route. As best I can tell, it's all in this binary file `/System/Library/Keyboard\ Layouts/AppleKeyboardLayouts.bundle/Contents/Resources/AppleKeyboardLayouts-L.dat` unfortunately.

Comment: @EmersonFarrugia No, but Ukrlele can convert what is in that binary into .keylayout format, which you can then edit.  Karabiner does its stuff on different files I think.

Answer (score 3):

You could also try to use [karabiner (elements)](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org).
[image: See immage]
This will change <kbd>Fn</kbd> ←→ <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and
will put <kbd>~</kbd> below <kbd>esc</kbd> touchbar/above <kbd>tab</kbd> (and <kbd>±§</kbd> next to <kbd>shift</kbd> key).

This worked for me on macOS Big Sur (Karabiner 13.xx) and on macOS Catalina (Karabiner 12.xx version).