Is it possible to remap ISO keyboard to ANSI?
I never had an ISO keyboard and it feels awkward to use. Unfortunately there was no ANSI mac to buy for me so I had to go with the ISO variant. And it's okay: I can get used to the tall enter and stuff, but what bugs me most is that instead of the `~ key I have §±.
My question is following: is there any way I can remap it so my 30+ years habit of using this key to open console etc would not result in frustration?

Which language do you use, and have you tried all the Input Sources for your language?

English ABC. After some search I found that the Karabiner app provides the virtual keyboard that does exactly what I wanted. But it also changes the other keyboard (hebrew) that I don't want to remap..

A similar question is at  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/365504/can-you-type-a-tilde-on-the-key-under-esc-on-a-european-iso-keyboard-set-to-us

You can easily make a custom layout to do what you want with Ukelele.
Here is one already made that may work for you.
